# Regular graphs with unimodal subdegrees that are not distance-regular

Tags: graph-theory, integer-sequences

[Distance regular graphs](http://graphclasses.org/classes/gc_1148.html) are known to exhibit the following property: starting from an arbitrary vertex $\alpha$, let $k_i$ denote the number of vertices at distance $i$ from $\alpha$ (in terms of shortest path lengths). Then the sequence $\{k_i\}_{0\leq i\leq d}$, where $d$ is the diameter of the graph, is unimodal (see e.g. [Taylor and Levingston's paper](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/BFb006254) for details).

Are there other classes of regular graphs with that property?

Comment: Almost all regular graphs, I believe, though I don't know if it has been proved.